# Devexpress GridContol check value change after double-select

Tags: c#, events, checkbox, devexpress, gridcontrol

I'm using DevExpress GridControl, where I have data binded and one column contains boolean flag *IsOrdered*. I registered for the event on my *SimpleGridView* called **CellValueChanged** because when my check field (meaning the *IsOrdered* value) is changed I want to perform some actions.
In the subscriber method I check `if (e.Column.FieldName == "IsOrdered")` and then I perform these operations.

The problem is that that **CellValueChanged** event is raised not until I check the checkbox (by double-click) and click somewhere else. That unfortunately causes an annoying problem here: for example when I have my row in that grid which has *IsOrdered* set to false (not selected), and I check this checkbox and immediatelly uncheck it and then I click somewhere else, the event is also raised. As I think that event should not be raised in such a case, because that *IsOrdered* value wasn't actually changed (it was *false*, then *true*, and finally *false* again).

Maybe there is some way to change this default behavior ? What would be perfect is to have **CellValueChanged** event raised immediately after checkbox is checked/unckecked, not having to click somewhere else the checkbox to have the event raised.

There is also a event called **CellValueChanging**, but it does not resolve my problem, because that event is raised actually before the *IsOrdered*'s value is changed, but in my subscriber method I need to know if that field's value is changed to *true* or *false*.

I will appreciate any help :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GridView.CellValueChanging` event and in this event you can change field's value by using [`ColumnView.SetRowCellValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_SetRowCellValuetopic(Ex4JUg)) method.
Here is example:

```
private void gridView1_CellValueChanging(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "IsOrdered")
    {
        gridView1.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, e.Column, e.Value);

        //Do your other staff here.               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use CheckEdit repository item inside the grid for that to work.

As stated on the [help](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1009): The editors of the DevExpress Editors Library can be used to perform in-place editing in the container controls provided by DevExpress. This topic describes the mechanism used to assign in-place editors to container controls.

You may also look at [this question](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A880) which states that "You should call the GridView.PostEditor method from a repository item's EditValueChanged event handler to immediately save the edited value to the grid's cell and the underlying column."

Comment: Thanks, it's actually fine, because I get the actual value for which the checkbox is changed, but the other problem there is that I cannot get the selected row from my GridView in that case, so I cannot perform any oprations on my object, which is actually the row in which the checkbox value is changed.

Comment: Have you consider using GetFocusedRow to get the selected row ?